# Jawbone tracking location (latitude/longitude) of logged sleep

Tags: jawbone

Just was curious if any one could tell the reason of jawbone tracking the latitude and longitude of sleep logged

Comment: I would imagine it is to get more insights on sleep patterns based on the geographic location, etc..